# Get a path to NPM package without entry point

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, react-scripts

A unconventional package contains a binary and nested modules but no entry point (no index script and no `main`), `react-scripts` is an example.

`require.resolve('react-scripts/bin/react-scripts')` works because `bin/react-scripts.js` module exists but `require.resolve('react-scripts')` results in error because the package has no entry point.

It's preferable to avoid relying on an expected location like `./node_modules/react-scripts` because it depends on project structure.

What is a good way to get full path to `react-scripts` module folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to extract package path from a nearest file that is expected to exist, which is `package.json`:

```
path.dirname(require.resolve('react-scripts/package.json'))
```

Still would appreciate alternative approaches to resolving a path to the the package.